# How to initialize a class next to the Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

## Problems

1) I would like to run a function that will clean some files from a particular folder. But I need to start as a new Thread and keep it running every 10 minutes.
Unfortunately, I could not figure out an effective way to execute this function inside a startup function or Global.asax.cs.

What is the best way of do this?

## File Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        SetThread(); // Isn't executing in my code. I don't know the because.
    }

    //Function Test
    private void ClearDirectories()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Line:" + i);
    }
    // Create a thread to execution
    private void SetThread()
    {
        //Initialize the job of Clear Path
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClearDirectories));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a web site to execute a schedulled task. And you have a problem.. This looks like [a clasic X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It is not a web application's responsibility to delete the files in intervals. You should write a separate program for it which can be called from some task scheduler.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal has someone example link? pls.

Comment: Maybe [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: @PriyankPanchal My code is in the description.